# Go basic authentication with Echo framework

Tags: go

Trying to get basic authentication to work using the Echo framework for Go. Have found several snippets of code, but not a complete set of code so far.

Have this basic program so far

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
   "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
  var html string;
    // Echo instance
    e := echo.New()

    // Route => handler
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {

  e.Group("/").Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func(username, password string, c echo.Context) (bool, error) {
    if username == "user" && password == "password" {
      html ="Authenticated"
      return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil
}))


        return c.HTML(http.StatusOK, html)
    })

    // Start server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

It prompts for user and password, but after authentication I get

> message    "Not Found"

Would appreciate any suggestions or link to working code using the basic authentication of the Echo framework.

Answer (score 2):

On top of what fstanis answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61721948/7331166), I would like to point out that you should be careful on the reference of the object of echo group.

So I think you should do this instead

```golang
e := echo.New()
g := e.Group("")
g.Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func(username, password string, c echo.Context) (bool, error) {
  if username == "joe" && password == "secret" {
    return true, nil
  }
  return false, nil
}))

// note that it was previously referring to the echo instance, not group.
g.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.HTML(http.StatusOK, html)
})
```

Note that `g` refers to to the group `e.Group("")`, This ensures that the handler for GET "/" will return the correct `html`. Thus leaving no ambiguity on whether basic authentication middleware is applied on the Group or the root instance of Echo `e`.

Answer (score 0):

You're registering a `Group` inside a callback for your route. Instead, you want to register group(s) at the top level and add routes to them:

```golang
e := echo.New()
g := e.Group("")
g.Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func(username, password string, c echo.Context) (bool, error) {
  if username == "joe" && password == "secret" {
    return true, nil
  }
  return false, nil
}))
e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.HTML(http.StatusOK, html)
})
```

Comment: How do I add the "/" route to the group?
>g := e.Group("/")

Didn't seem to work as the basicauth is not getting triggrered
comments don't seem to allow formatting so can't put updated code.

Comment: Just add a "" route? The routes are appended like suffixes, so that should work.